# Безопасная new Function(str)

Tags: node.js, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Необходимо вычислить строку. Реализовал через `new Function(str)`. Вопрос такой: с точки зрения безопасности, достаточно ли проверить регуляркой запуск метода (функции) и отсутствие операций присваивания?

```
var evalute = function (expr, context) {
  expr = expr.replace(/\s+/g, '');
  if (/[^^\+\-\*\/\<\>\=]\(|[^\<\>\!\=]\=[^\=]/.test(expr)) {
    throw new Error('bad expression '+expr);
  }
  return (new Function('return ' + expr).bind(context))();
};
```

Comment: Вычислить арифметическое выражение надо? Вроде 2+7?

Вот такого типа хак не пугает?

    var arr=[1,2,3];
    console.log(evalute("this.length--",arr),arr);

Comment: Операторы - !, +, -, /, *, <, >, >=, <=. В методах нужды нет, вот я их и "забанил" от греха подальше. Операции проводить над строками, числами, объектами, булевыми значениями.

Comment: Примеры выражений, которые вы собрались запускать, покажите.

Comment: @eicto, да, это беда. Про даблплюс и минус забыл.

Comment: Ну я про что говорю... Думаю, сама по себе идея не очень хороша. Много про что можно забыть, если вам нужно арифметику таким образом считать, то, наверное, лучше честно парсить, вот, например, библиотека, которая, может быть, вам подойдет   
http://mathjs.org/docs/index.html

Comment: На `mathjs` смотрел, но такую тащить его ради того функционала, что можно влепить <20 строк, как-то не хочется.

> примеры выражений, которые вы собрались запускать покажите.

Пишу велосипед (фильтрация на сайт). В базе хранится фильтры (`{name: .., prop1: ..., prop2: ...}`). Надо к некоторым фильтрам пришить методы, которые будут возвращать какое-нибудь значение (`this.prop1+this.prop2`). Добавлять эти методы будет человек, не знакомый с программированием, поэтому хочу сделать так, чтобы он мог этот метод написать одной строчкой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну я вам говорю - сэкономите на байтах (да ещё и не на своих) - потеряете где-нибудь в безопасности или точности, в чем проблема сделать

```
npm install mathjs
```

и заняться чем-нибудь более интересным, чем изобретение лисопеда (вы в результате всё равно парсер напишите, после десятка багрепортов).

А для людей незнакомых с программированием надо писать жестко ограничивающие интерфейсы.